# basic linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck with the following linear algebra problem:

given a basis $ \{e_{1} ... e_{n}\} $, I can define products $ \{p_{1} ... p_{m} \} $ as linear combination of the basis and the products itself:

$$
p_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^m u_{ij} p_{j} + \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}e_{ij} 
$$

My goal is to represent each product only as a combination of the basis.

$$
p_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^n s_{ij} e_{j} 
$$

any hint for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix $P=UP+AE$. This means that $P=(1-U)^{-1}AE$.

This will break down if $1-U$ is degenerate, e.g., if $U=1$, and your representation is trivial: $u_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and $a_{ij}=0$.

Comment: simple and effective explanation. thanks! But what is the interpretation when 1-U is degenerate? the trivial case U=1 is not the only one that will make problem singular. Does it mean that I have products cycles which cannot be represented as a combination of 'base' elements. Can I define a new element in the base that replaces the cycle and makes the problem non-singular ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "products", but changing the basis vectors $e_i$ will not help; you need to fix $U$.

Comment: in my case the basis is something like (water, milk, sugar, salt, lemon, etc) and products maybe drinks. Using linear combinations you can basically define your recipe. I can also mix drinks with other drinks to get the new drink. That's where the formula came from. So the problem that I asked would be: what does it take in total to mix a given drink (in terms of basic ingredients)? If the matrix is singular that means that the drink is impossible to mix. That won't occur in this example but in my case 'my products' can have cycles and I need to think how to handle it.

Comment: If you declare your "products" to be your "basis", then you are done right away. Alternatively, I think that your $U$ has non-negative elements and 0 diagonal (i.e., each drink is defined without mentioning itself and all ingredients are only added), in which case I think $1-U$ should be non-degenerate (ask a separate question about that!)

Comment: If you got an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).